# When should we take angular energy and kinetic energy together when doing work energy theorem?

Tags: energy

On page-274 Kleppner and Kolenkow, An introduction to classical mechanics, it is said that we can apply the rotational work-energy theorem and translational work-energy theorem separately in many problems.

However, how do you decide if on a given problem that if it can be applied separately or not? I came across some problems involving constraint motions where it couldn't be and some other problems where it could be.

---

Example of a problem where we have to apply both together:

> A wheel of radius $r$ and moment of inertia $I$ about its axis is fixed at the top of an inclined play of inclination $\theta$ as shown in the figure (10-W2). A string is wrapped around the wheel and its free end supports a block of mass $M$ which can slide on the plane. Initially, the wheel is rotating at a speed of $\omega$ in a direction such that the block moves up the ramp. How far will the block move before stopping?

[image]

So, in the above problem, you have to consider both the kinetic energy of the block and the angular energy of the wheel together when doing energy conservation and equate that to potential energy change.

---

I am hypothesizing that for constraint problems, we have to consider using the combined energy conservation equation and for others, we can get away with using it individually. I wish for an answer which explains the reasoning of when we use the lumped energy conservation and when we can use individual conservation (i.e: kinetic and potential separately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Energy is energy - it does not divide itself into translational energy and rotational energy. For any object we always have

Net work done on object = increase in energy of the object

The right hand side may have several terms, some of which represent kinetic energy and some of which represent potential energy. The left hand side may include one or more negative terms representing the energy lost to dissipative forces such as drag or friction.

In a problem with several objects you can apply this equation to each object separately, as long as you know the magnitude of all of the forces that are doing work on the object. Sometimes it is simpler to apply the work-energy equation to the system as a whole because that lets you ignore internal forces between two objects in the system, such as the tension in the rope in your example. This is because Newton’s third law means that the work done by internal forces nets to zero across the system as a whole.

Comment: Wait so does the tension do work as it pulls up the block? ( in the qsn posted)

Comment: @Buraian Yes, the tension in the rope does work on the block, but it does equal and opposite negative work on the wheel (or you can think of this as work done *by* the wheel). This slows the wheel down as the block moves up the ramp. If you consider block and wheel together then work done by the tension nets to zero.